# Is it possible to find out who called a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to find out who called a stored procedure? I'm using the following query to identify the execution count etc. but I'm unable to identify which job / trigger / process is calling it. Any ideas about it please?

```
SELECT  
    a.execution_count, OBJECT_NAME(objectid) Name,
    (CASE WHEN a.statement_end_offset = -1 
             THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), b.text)) * 2
             ELSE a.statement_end_offset
     END - a.statement_start_offset) / 2),
    b.dbid, dbname = db_name(b.dbid), b.objectid,
    a.creation_time, a.last_execution_time, a.* 
FROM  
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats a 
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) AS b
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME(objectid) = 'Rebuild_Indexes' 
ORDER BY 
    a.last_execution_time
ESCquery_text = SUBSTRING(b.text,a.statement_start_offset/2,
```

Comment: What is _who_?  The `@@SPID` and `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` are available.  Do you want to look at fingerprints through the keyboard and see who _really_ started the application?  `select *   from sys.dm_exec_connections as EC inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions as ES on ES.session_id = EC.session_id where EC.session_id = @@SPID`?

Comment: A common theme you'll see in the answers is that, without logging everything, it's impossible to see who _called_ a stored proc; rather, you can see who _is calling_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Adam Machanic's [Who is Active](http://whoisactive.com) stored procedure - this returns all sorts of info about active statements, including the user who launched them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Needed something like it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see who is executing a stored procedure, one way to go about this is to create a server-side Trace and capture the `SP:Completed` event.  The data provided by this event class will give you all the caller information you should need.

Reference: [BOL documentation on the `SP:Completed` Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188675.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you fire up SQL profiler, it will show you the network id of the NT user, I suggest you run trace profiler on the server its self if this is an occasional usage. alternately if you are not using simple recovery mode, then the answer will be in the transaction log backup. However this is not easy to analyse or read.

Comment: Thanks , I have identified a dtsx package.

Answer (score 1):

Use option with [Dynamic Management Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188068%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). DMVs provide a simple and familiar relational interface for gathering critical system information from your SQL Server.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(der.database_id) AS databaseName,
       OBJECT_NAME(objectid),
       der.session_id,
       login_name,
       USER_NAME(der.user_id) AS user_name,
       der.command,
       dest.text AS [CommandText],
       des.login_time,
       des.[host_name],
       dec.client_net_address,
       des.[program_name],       
       der.status
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests der
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections dec ON der.session_id = dec.session_id
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions des ON der.session_id = des.session_id
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE des.is_user_process = 1 
  --AND OBJECT_NAME(objectid) = 'Rebuild_Indexes'
```